# Case-when error when creating individual monthly values

Tags: sql, case-when

If I have the following

```
ID   Disputes_Count    Month-Year
123  45                12020
123  85                32020
```

I want the result to be

```
ID   Jan_2020_Disputes   Mar_2020_Disputes
123  45                  85
```

I tried this:

```
proc sql;
create table disputes_count as 
select ID,
sum(case when Month_Year = '12020' then Dispute_Count else 0 end) as January_2020_Disputes,
sum(case when Month_Year = '32020' then Dispute_Count else 0 end) as Mar_2020_Disputes,
from rb.disputes
group by ID;
quit;
```

However the output I got with this is the following:

```
ID     January_2020_Disputes     Mar_2020_Disputes
              0                        7
```

Please help!

Comment: Your query should work. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Thats what I thought! SAS Enterprise guide -postgres

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/50596/4

Comment: Maybe you query the wrong table?